# How to replicate this on React?

Tags: reactjs, html5-canvas

I saw some post on Dribbble and face that post https://dribbble.com/shots/6546603-AI-Assistant. In the commentary section, there's a link with an implementation using canvas or something like that. I want to include this in my project.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using some lib like [Three.js](https://threejs.org/).
In React we have this lib called [react-three-fiber](https://github.com/pmndrs/react-three-fiber) that is based on Three.js